# Permutations Runtime Analysis: Iterative DP Solution

Tags: python, runtime, dynamic-programming

My iterative DP solution is as follows:

```
def permutations(string):
    # let n = len(string)
    N = [[] for _ in range(len(string) + 1)] # O(n)

    N[0].append("")

    for i in range(1, len(string) + 1): # O(n)
        N[i] = [perm[:j] + string[i - 1] + perm[j:] for j in range(i) for perm in N[i - 1]] # O(???)

    return N[-1]
```

However, I'm having trouble analyzing the runtime of the above program. Specifically, bounding the runtime of the line `for perm in N[i - 1]`. I'm aware that the recursive solution is `O(n!)`, but how can we find the runtime of the above program without relying on knowing the recursive runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider

```
N[i] = [perm[:j] + string[i - 1] + perm[j:] for j in range(i) for perm in N[i - 1]]
```

as our main interest.

We can rewrite it as

```
line 1: for i in range(1, len(string) + 1):                      # O(n)
line 2:     N[i] = []                                            # O(n)
line 3:     for j in range(i):                                   # O(sum i from 1 to n)
line 4:         for perm in N[i - 1]:                            # O(sum len(Ni) from 1 to n)
line 5:             N[i].append(perm[:j] + string[i - 1] + perm[j:])
```

Now, for `i = 1`, `line 3` and `line 4` would run a single time, leaving `N[1]` with a single element of `string[0]`.

For `i = 2`, `line 3` would run twice and `line 4` would run a single time for the first run and 2 for the second, leaving `N[2]` with three elements.

Seeing the pattern? lets fast forward. 6, 24, 120, 720.

```
N   total runs  diff
1   1           1
2   3           2 
3   9           6
4   33          24
5   153         120
...
```

So we get a total complexity of

```
  n
 ____
 \ 
  >   k!
 /___
k = 0       (asciiart courtesy of sympy)
```

Simplifying it is pretty complicated (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/) but we can assure it is within the `O(n!)` boundary, since the summation of `k*k!` from 1 to n is `(n+1)! - 1`, so we get a total run time of `O(n!)`, **without relying on the known recursive runtime**.